# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed for <ul>

Tags: html, xhtml

This code is so simple but still throw "The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed." error... where did it go wrong??

```
<br><h2>h2</h2></br>
<ul> 
    <li> li </li>
    <li> li </li>     
</ul>
```

create a html in my code

Comment: Is that the entire document? If so, then the br element is the root element and the `<ul>` tag starts a new element outside the root element, hence it's not well formed.

Comment: Also,  `<br>` tag doesn't need ending `</br>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `</br>` Remove that.

A `<br>` element is for causing a line break. This action takes place by itself with no closing tag.